# Same data type, but can't have the same name?

Tags: jhipster

Some of our data entities have more than one collection of child entities with the same data type. Here is a JDL file to illustrate the relationship.

```
entity Parent {
  name String
  headOfHousehold Boolean
}

entity Child {
  name String
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Child{parent(name)} to Parent{boys}
  Child{parent(name)} to Parent{girls}
}
```

When I run the import command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Error at entity Parent: relationship name is not synchronized {
    "otherEntityName": "child",
    "otherEntityRelationshipName": "parent",
    "relationshipName": "girls",
    "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
    "otherEntity": "[Child Entity]",
    "otherEntityField": "id",
    "ownerSide": false,
    "collection": true,
    "otherSideReferenceExists": false,
    "otherEntityIsEmbedded": false
} with {
    "otherEntityField": "name",
    "otherEntityName": "parent",
    "otherEntityRelationshipName": "boys",
    "relationshipName": "parent",
    "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
    "otherEntity": "[Parent Entity]"
}
```

I don't know what "synchronized" means in the message.

After renaming the Child entity,

```
entity Parent {
    name String
    headOfHousehold Boolean
}

entity Boy {
    name String
}

entity Girl {
    name String
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Boy{parent(name)} to Parent{boys}
    Girl{parent(name)} to Parent{girls}
}
```

The import process will work without the error.

In JPA, the following entity class structure is correct.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Collection<Child> boys;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Collection<Child> girls;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    // ...
}
```

Why JHipster doesn't work for the same entity class structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't about duplicating types, but duplicating names.
You named the relationship `parent` in both cases and they are in the same Child class.  Using `boysParent` and `girlsParent` would have worked:

```
relationship ManyToOne {
  Child{boysParent(name)} to Parent{boys}
  Child{girlsParent(name)} to Parent{girls}
}
```

Have a look at the documentation: https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/#two-one-to-many-relationships-on-the-same-two-entities

Comment: Interesting! I thought using the same parent name on the child side won't cause a naming clash. The generated code has two entities: Boy and Girl., but not Child. That yields the same end result as defining two entities with the same attributes.